# Can we really call them adverbs?

Tags: parts-of-speech, definition

- Only adv. :as recently as : not before
- Merely adv. :nothing more than

I think 1 is more like a preposition and 2 is a noun+preposition.
Both are from a Merriam Webster dictionary.

Comment: Are you referring to the words *only* and *merely*, or to their definitions?

Comment: I'm referring to a part of speech between a word and a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must misunderstand what adverbs and prepositions are.

An **adverb** *describes a verb* or adds additional detail to a verb.

A **preposition** tells you *where or when* something is *in relation to something else*.

In the complete statements "I am **only** a man" or "I am **merely** a man", the words in question do not show when or where the subject is, or place the subject in any relative position to anything else. There isn't even anything else mentioned or implied in these statements that the subject could be in a relative position to. They are not acting as prepositions.

What these words *do* is add detail to the verb 'am'. "I am a man" - that is a true and complete statement. "I am *merely* (or *only*) a man" adds the detail that the person is a man *and nothing more*.

They *are* both adverbs - undeniably so. I can't understand why that would be in question.

Comment: But at least should definition 1 be a prepositional phrase?

Comment: @user126927 are you talking about the **words** or their definitions?? A single word cannot be a phrase! As a general rule you should be able to remove an adverb and still understand the sentence because they *add* detail. You couldn't remove a preposition and still get the same meaning.

Comment: I'm talking about the definition of the word.

Comment: It's so much different from the other definitions of adverbs.

Comment: I think I should add a new question.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are misunderstanding how the dictionary works. The "adv." in your examples pertains to the word **before** it, and not the definition after it.