# Don't word defintions need to be in one of five phrase types?

Tags: definition, dictionaries

There are noun phrases, adjective phrases, adverb phrases, verb phrases, prepositional phrases. Word definitions don't need to be in one of five types?

Comment: Well, for a quick example (if I understand you), "a", "an", and "the" are articles.  Maybe look at interrogatories and exclamations.

Comment: conjunctions, determiners, numerals.  Pronouns are often classed separately from nouns.  That makes 9.  Then there are some special cases, like the particle  to in infinitives.  An "adverb" is a catch all for lots of different types of word.

Comment: You missed two out: noun phrase, e.g. _The guy who fainted_ and  determinative phrase", e.g. _almost every_.  So there are six phrasal categories altogether.

Comment: There are six phrasal categories altogether: verb, noun, adjective, adverb, preposition and determinative. The two remaining parts of speech, coordinator and subordinator, can't function as head of a corresponding phrase but serve as markers of coordination and subordination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, there are more than 5 phrase types. There are *infinitive phrases*, *gerund phrases* and *absolute phrases* to name a few more. I think there are about 9 or 10 phrase types taught, but perhaps it is safer to say that for any phrase to be valid, it must have a recognisable grammatical structure.

This question appears to be the promised follow-up to your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270484/can-we-really-call-them-adverbs/270493?noredirect=1#comment504384_270493) in which you were asking why two adverbs were not classed as prepositions when their dictionary definitions appeared to be prepositional phrases. Obviously, if you are asked to describe a noun (for example 'a car') you are going to have to use an *adjective phrase* to do so ('a road vehicle with an engine, four wheels, and seats'). Just because one is the definition of the other does not mean that both the word and the phrase that define it are nouns, or adjectives, or whatever. Just as an adjective describes a noun, it shouldn't be surprising that adjective phrases - and likely other kinds of phrases too - are found in the dictionary as definitions of all kinds of words.

Comment: Expressions headed by an infinitival verb (e.g. _**to turn back now** would be a disaster_) or by a gerund-participial one (e.g. _**Bringing your dad along** was a great idea_) are clauses not phrases. And absolutes are also clauses, not phrases.